# How to read .log file using java?

Tags: java, java-8

I have .log file which I put into resources in new raceData folder, and I want to read this file and output as List but when Im trying to read file I have "No such file or directory" exception.
My code:

```
try{
        FileInputStream readFile = new FileInputStream("raceData/start.log");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;
       
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
           
            System.out.println (strLine);
        }
        fstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
```

Comment: You are giving a relative path. That means that the JVM will use its working directory + your path. Hint: that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Note that your code can be replaced by just `Files.lines(Path.of("raceData/start.log")).forEach(System.out::println);`. Prefer NIO over old IO if possible.

Comment: If it is in _resources_ it might be a _resource_ on the **class path**. As the application can be packed in a .jar file (zip file), a resource should be read-only and not accessed as `File/FileInputStream`, but as `getClass(),getResourceAsStream("/raceData/start.log")`. Also `new InputStreamReader` should have an added parameter with the encoding/charset.

Comment: @Zabuzard or just `Files.copy(Paths.get("raceData/start.log"), System.out);`, not wasting time to search for line breaks and create substrings, just to assemble them with new line breaks in the output stream…

Comment: Thats a pretty neat usage of stream copying, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file is relative to your java.exe's current directory. If you run it from an IDE, it's usually att the project root.

For testing, try using an absolute path.

Comment: That is horrible advice. `Class.getResource()` is the way to go. Don't hard-code paths, ever. You only get into trouble when you want to deploy the software. You need to be able to handle arbitrary paths anyways because users can deploy the finished software anywhere.

Comment: @Polygnome getResource is not always trhe way to go. It depends on there the file is located. And here I am trying to help the guy to make it work, i.e. solve the immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

"No such file or directory" is pretty self-explanatory. This can mean either the directory/file is not there, or you are trying to access something over a linked "virtual" drive.

USe System.getProperty("user.dir") to confirm the working directory that would be applied to your relative path

Answer (score 0):

Your path is relative, it starts from the point where the application executes and searches there for the `raceData` folder.
Just put the absolute path instead of the relative one (Starting from `/` on Linux or `{Drive}:\` on windows

[More about relative and absolute paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)